# Blazor EditForm adding InputNumber fields

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor EditForm like this:

```
<EditForm Model="EntryModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" @oninput="OnInput" >
                    //...other stuff...
                    @foreach (var v in EntryModel.VehiclePremiums)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@v.vehicleid</td>
                            <td>@v.vehicleMake</td>
                            <td>@v.vehicleModel</td>
                            <td><InputNumber @bind-Value="@v.premium" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    }
                   //...other stuff
</EditForm>
```

Now as the user types into the InputNumber field, I want to sum up the value on all these fields.
So, in the OnInput function, I do this:

```
public void OnInput(){
    total_premium = EntryModel.VehiclePremiums.Select(vp => vp.premium).Sum();
}
```

This gives me a form like this:
[image]

The problem is that when I enter premium for the first car, the total is not updated. When I enter for the second car, the total is updated but current value is not included. Kind of strange behavior. The sum is always one field behind.

How should I sum up these fields as the user types in (either while inputting or after losing focus, doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested code here...

Note that I'm not using the InputNumber component. It's easier and more flexible to work with Html input number tag

```
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="entryModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <InputText @bind-Value="entryModel.ID"></InputText>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Make</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td>Premium</td>
                <td>@total_premium.ToString()</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var v in entryModel.VehiclePremiums)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@v.VehicleID</td>
                    <td>@v.VehicleMake</td>
                    <td>@v.VehicleModel</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" value="@v.Premium" @onchange="@((args) => { v.Premium = Convert.ToInt32(args.Value);
                                      total_premium = entryModel.VehiclePremiums.Select(vp => vp.Premium).Sum();})" />
                   </td>
                
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</EditForm>


@code
{
    private EntryModel entryModel;
    private int total_premium;

  
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        entryModel = new EntryModel
        {
            ID = "1",
            VehiclePremiums = new List<VehiclePremium>
                           {
                  new VehiclePremium{VehicleID = "1",  VehicleMake="Make1", VehicleModel="Model1", Premium=0},
                  new VehiclePremium{VehicleID = "2",  VehicleMake="Make2", VehicleModel="Model2", Premium=0},
                  new VehiclePremium{VehicleID = "3",  VehicleMake="Make3", VehicleModel="Model3", Premium=0},
                  new VehiclePremium{VehicleID = "4",  VehicleMake="Make4", VehicleModel="Model4", Premium=0}
                 }
        };
    }


    public class VehiclePremium
    {
        public string VehicleID { get; set; }
        public string VehicleMake { get; set; }
        public string VehicleModel { get; set; }
        public int Premium { get; set; }

    }

    public class EntryModel
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<VehiclePremium> VehiclePremiums { get; set; }
    }

}
```