# EditForm <InputNumber> needs to be entered as int not string, but it wont let me

Tags: database, forms, validation, input, razor

[image]

Hi so I'm learning about razor, and razor pages; and I'm working on adding items to a simple db.

I noticed something odd with the  input in my form when I try to enter a Quantity (should be a int) it throws an error when I press 1 or any number; and says it should be string/Array/collection? Whats that about??

code excerpt from Products.razor:

```
@if (products != null) // Insert form 
{
<EditForm Model="@product" OnValidSubmit="@HandleAdd">
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />
  <ValidationSummary />
 
  <InputText placeholder="Product Name" id="ProductName" @bind-Value="@product.ProductName" />
  <br />
  <InputText placeholder="Unit of Measurement" id="Unit" @bind-Value="@product.Unit" />
  <br />
  <InputNumber min="1" step="1" placeholder="Quantity" id="Quantity" @bind-Value="@product.Quantity" />
  <br />
  <InputNumber min="0.01" step="0.01" placeholder="Unit Price" id="UnitPrice" @bind-Value="@product.UnitPrice" />
  <br />
  <InputText placeholder="Category" id="Category" @bind-Value="@product.Category" />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
```

Wierd error in colsole:
[image]

I did notice someone had an idea on a un-related question:
[Blazor EditForm adding InputNumber fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303120/blazor-editform-adding-inputnumber-fields)
[image]

[image]

But I treid that and its still not working; and additionally with this form code; now the little green border box indicating valid input doesnt light up.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Made a mistake in the constrution of my Product class applying a [MaxLength] attribute to my Quantity.

Removed it, add new migrations, and now it works :)